# Replacing references in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pass-by-reference

I have a pythonic list, with objects which may be repeated. For example,

```
t_list = [object1, object2, object3, object1, object1, object5]
```

To eliminate the repetitions I use `list(set(t_list))`. But in my data scheme there are many objects, which contain references to the elements of `t_list`. So, if I remove some elements from list, the references to they remain.

I need to automatically replace all existing references after removing repetitions. For example, if I remove the 3rd and 4th elements from `t_list`, references will point to `t_list[0]`.

How can I do that without looping over all elements of the data scheme? Is this possible?

Comment: So for your example, the result would be `[object1, object2, object3, t_list[0], t_list[0], object5]`?

Comment: Give [this `OrderedSet` recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) a try, it may be just the data structure you need.

Comment: Let me get this straight - say you have code like [found in this gist](https://gist.github.com/waynew/166a1c4a7f4981b29970). Say you remove all the `list_one` from `t_list`, you want to propagate that removal to `other_list`??

Comment: How does your data model reference items in t_list? Do you mean you have indices stored in the scheme instead of object references? Does your data have a reference to t_list? From what you say it sounds like you have nothing more to do, there is no need to alter the data.

Comment: @Reti43, no, the result must be `list(set(t_list))`, i.e. `[object1, object2, object3, object5]`.

Comment: @WayneWerner, no, I want to remove only repetitions from `t_list`, i.e. remove `t_list[2:4]`. All references to the `t_list[2]` and `t_list[4]` (Has `other_list` such references? I don't see it in example.) must be replaced to the `t_list[0]`. No more removals, except   `t_list[2]` and `t_list[4]`.

Comment: @hege_hegedus, no, I haven't indices, I have only object references (different objects, where these references stores as a field value). My data haven't a reference to the `t_list`, only to the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have a list, and a data object:

```
t_list = [object1, object2, object3, object1, object1, object5]
# ...
data = {
    'some_path': t_list[1],
    'some_more': {
        t_list[3]
    }
};
```

That means your data doesn't depend on the list in any form. Your data has references to objects in the list, but those references are entirely independent from `t_list`. That means if you alter the list:

```
t_list = list(set(t_list))
```

that does not have any effect on your `data` object, no further action is required. You can even ignore that list.

EDIT:

This small diagram illustrates the objects, lists and references between them in memory:

[image]

The transformation on `t_list` will remove any multiple references from it, but data is not altered in any way.